# Subsetting from a list of data.frames based on a variable in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, lapply

I have a data.frame **[HERE](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/k.csv)**. Using `subset()` I'm trying to take out `study.names` (a column in the data.frame) that have only `1`s for variable `post` and not `2` or `3`.

Therefore, my **desired output** is to find out how many studies have only `post == 1`, with no `post == 2`, or `3`.

Here is what I tried but without success:

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/k.csv", h = T) # The data

m <- split(D, D$study.name) ; m[[1]] <- NULL  # split by `study.names`

subset(m, post == 1 & post != 2 & post != 3)  # subset studies with only post == 1 
                                              # but not post == 2 and post == 3


Error: object 'post' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that `subset` does not work on lists like you are expecting it to.

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/k.csv", h = T) # The data

m <- split(D, D$study.name) ; 

m[[1]] <- NULL  # split by `study.names`

table(sapply(m, function(x) all(x[["post"]]==1)) )
# FALSE  TRUE 
# 5     2
```

And a tidyverse solution:

```
D %>% group_by(study.name) %>% summarise(only_1=all(post==1))
# study.name only_1
# <fct>      <lgl> 
#   1 ""         NA    
# 2 Bit.KnoA   FALSE 
# 3 Bit.KnoB   FALSE 
# 4 ChandlerA  TRUE  
# 5 Mubarak    FALSE 
# 6 Sheen      FALSE 
# 7 Shin.Ellis FALSE 
# 8 Trus.Hsu   TRUE 

D %>% group_by(study.name) %>% summarise(only_1=all(post==1)) %>% summarise(tot=sum(only_1, na.rm = T))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
# tot
# <int>
#   1     2
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `subset` by any chance?

Comment: `subset` is used to filter data.frames, vectors, or matrices, but not lists. You could do it but it would be convoluted, and would still require an `*apply` function with some extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only `1` records, you could check to see if the number of `1` elements in `post` equal the number of rows of a `data.frame`.

`only_1 <- sapply(m, function(x) sum(x$post == 1) == nrow(x))`

This would return

```
  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB  ChandlerA    Mubarak      Sheen Shin.Ellis   Trus.Hsu 
     FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE
```

The number of studies that have only 1 values is then:

```
sum(only_1)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using the `subset` function looks for an object named `post` in your global environment, but it doesn't exist as it's just a column within the data.

Easy way to do this is to construct a logical condition with `sapply` utilizing the `all` function, and then subset the list that way:

```
cond <- sapply(m, function(df) all(df$post == 1))

m[cond]
```

Comment: `df` is the name of the function argument, it should definitely run